# Node Criar uma API para validar login com AD do Azure

Tags: node.js, microsoft-azure, active-directory

Alguem sabe como eu conseguiria criar uma API para validar o login com o AD do Azure e devolver um token?

Comment: Você já tentou alguma coisa? poste algo para que possamos lhe ajudar?

Comment: Eu havia tentado usar o Passport-Azure com o Passport ... mas n tinha conseguido a parte de login ainda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro voce deve iniciar seu projeto, para te ajudar com essas questoes de rotas, voce pode usar o [Express generator](https://github.com/expressjs/generator), em seguida pode usar o [Passport-Azure](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad)

Um Exemplo simples...

```
app.get('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    log.info('Login was called in the Sample');
    res.redirect('/');
});
```